# how to auto populate form fields using data from the server?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd

I created a form in React. When the user enters a value in the 'gage id' field, if that value exists in the database, the system should automatically populate other fields based on that input. How can I achieve this in React?
hear is my code:

```
function WorkOrderRef() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm()
  const [id, setId] = useState()
const [gageInfo, setGageInfo] = useState()
const meta = {
    columns: 2,
    fields: [
      {
        key: "Id",
        label: "ID",
        placeholder: "",
        onChange: (e) => setId(e.target.value),
      },
      {
        key: "description",
        label: "Description",
        placeholder: "",
        //value: referenceData.name,
      },
      {
        key: "serial number",
        label: "Serial Number",
        placeholder: "",
      },
      {
        key: "due date",
        label: "Due Date",
        placeholder: "",
        widget: "date-picker",
      },
      {
        key: "colibration",
        label: "Colibration",
        widget: "select",
        options,
      },
    ],
  }
useEffect(() => {
    try {
      if (id) {
        console.log(id)
        fetch(`api/id=${id}`)
          .then((result) => result.json())
          .then((response) => setGageInfo(response))
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }, [id])
return (
    <Fragment>
        <Form form={form} onFinish={handleFinish}>
          <FormBuilder meta={meta} form={form} />
          <Form.Item className="ant-form-item--btn">
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Add
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
</Fragment>
  )
}

export default WorkOrderRef
```

In reality, I can fetch data related to the "gage id" from the server, but I'm finding it challenging to display that data in the form fields. How can I make this happen in React?

Comment: Which library you are using for Form handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `form.setFieldsValue. Take a look into [this](https://ant.design/components/form#formuseforminstance) section of antd docs.
As you can see in Button component, it's reseting all fields of the form but you can use this to assign data to your form too:

```
<Button onClick={() => form.setFieldsValue({
  description: 'item description',
  'serial number': 'abc123'
  ...
})} />;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your previous answer. Is it possible to use 'setFiledValue' in Ant Design Pro Form? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: I neve used pro form before but taking a quick look into docs I saw many similar functions so I think they are the same

Answer (score 0):

other way to populate with data from db is using initialValues like this you can do that:

```
<Form
  initialValues={{ description: currentObj?.description }}
  onFinish={onFinish}
```